# PSQL - Returning % of Completed and Not Completed by column in a crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

Here's my table called "completions"

| name | status | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Completed | Sales |
| Dave | Completed | HR |
| Jim | Not Completed | Sales |
| Frank | Not Completed | HR |
| Sarah | Completed | Tech |

I would like to return a crosstab query by department that calculates the percentage of completed and not completed by department like below

| Status | HR | Sales | Tech |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Completed | 50% | 50% | 100% |
| Not Completed | 50% | 50% | 0% |

How ever I'm struggling to return the percentage calculation of completed and not completed for each department

Here's the query i've written currently

```
    select * from crosstab($$
    SELECT status, department, count(distinct status) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over() 
    FROM completions
    GROUP BY status, department
    ORDER BY status
    $$,
    $$select distinct department FROM completions ORDER BY department
    $$
    ) as ("Status" varchar, "HR" varchar, "Sales" varchar, "Tech" varchar)
```

I cant wrap my head around the percentage calculation

Here is also a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aE47gUC6)

Comment: To make things clearer, add one more row of sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: @jarlh updated to reflect a new "Tech" department where completion should be 100% as that one record would reflect 100% completed and 0% not completed

Comment: @jarlh apologies, updated again to reflect expected result

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/UXpi2R3u) I went for but would be interesting to here if a better alternative is there

More importantly

```
Round((count(*)/sum(count(status)) over(partition by department)) * 100)
```

Which gets the `(columnCount / total) * 100` for percentage